# Angularjs - how to set template content from server json answer?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-routing

I need to set template of my route dynamic. For examle, I have this config (route):

```
$routeProvider.when('/page', {
  templateUrl: '/dynamic-page',
});
```

But from `/dynamic-page` I get JSON:

```
{
    "title": "Title of the page",
    "content": "Html-content of the view"
}
```

I need, to set template from `content` key of the server answer, and value of the `title` key I need to pass into controller.

Tell me please, it is possible?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not found the right way to solve the problem, so I decided it so:

1. in a `$rootScope` I create `pageTitle` variable, that contains my page title
2. i bind `pageTitle` to the `title` of my html
3. from server now I receive only html-content with `ng-init="$root.pageTitle='Page title'"`

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by an alternate approach.

```
$routeProvider.when('/page', {
  template: ''
});
```

Now you need to get data. That you can do in resolve block in route provider or can call it via ajax in controller.

Comment: How I can set route template from resolve section in this way?

Comment: You can use resolve like this  resolve: {
                info: yourService
            }

Comment: Now your service will return a promise that will have data as per your snippet. Now, in controller, simply pass this info as parameter in function. info.title will give you title which you can set in scope and info.content will be the html that you can set in html by dom manipulation.